# Python matrices

Tags: python, matrix

I want to make a matrix in python with three columns per row and to be able to index them by any one of the rows. Each value in the matrix is unique.

From what I can tell, I can set up a matrix like:

```
matrix = [["username", "name", "password"], ["username2","name2","password2"]...]
```

However, I don't know how to access an element from it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list of lists:

```
In [64]: matrix = [["username", "name", "password"],["username2","name2","password2"]]

In [65]: matrix
Out[65]: [['username', 'name', 'password'], ['username2', 'name2', 'password2']]
```

Access the first row (since Python uses 0-based indexing):

```
In [66]: matrix[0]
Out[66]: ['username', 'name', 'password']
```

Access the second item in the first row:

```
In [67]: matrix[0][1]
Out[67]: 'name'
```

---

A list of lists is not a good choice of data structure 
if you want to look up names based on usernames.
To do that, you'd have to loop through (potentially) all the items in the `matrix`
to find the item whose username matches the specified username.
The time to complete the search would grow linearly with the number of rows in the matrix.

In contrast, dicts have, on average, [constant-time lookups](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) no matter how many
keys are in the dict. So, for example, if you were to define

```
matrix = {
    'capitano': {'name':'Othello', 'password':'desi123'}
    'thewife': {'name':'Desdemona', 'password':'3apples'}
    }
```

(where `'capitano'` and `'thewife'` are usernames)

then to find the name of the person with username `'capitano'`, you would use

```
matrix['capitano']['name']
```

and Python would return `'Othello'`.

---

Functions are first-class objects in Python: You can pass them around as objects, just as you would a number or a string. So, for example, you can store a function as the value in a dict's (key, value) pair:

```
from __future__ import print_function    
matrix = {'hello': {'action': lambda: print('hello')} }
```

Then to call the function, (note the parentheses):

```
matrix['hello']['action']()
# hello
```

Comment: could i search for matrix[username] and return matrix[name]

Comment: You could, but you'd probably be better off with a different data structure if that is the kind of lookup you plan to do frequently. A dict of dicts might be more appropriate in that case. I've edited my post to show what I mean.

Comment: By the way, it helps to sit down with a piece of paper and list **all** the things you want to do with `matrix` -- all the ways you want to access information, if you want to iterate through the items, add or remove items, assign new values, perform searches, etc. Only when you have a complete list can you make an intelligent choice of data structure.

Comment: Is there any way i could embed a command in it, for example:

    `matrix = {
        'hello': {'action':print("hello"), 'info':'Prints hello'}
    }`

Comment: You can store the function object itself, and call it later by appending open and closed parentheses. See above for an example.

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to install a library, consider using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).  It has a rich set of tools for efficiently handling rectangular multidimensional arrays and slicing them.

Answer (score 1):

What you've demonstrated is a matrix which is comprised of a list of lists.

You can access the elements by using the index of the row and column:

```
>>> matrix[0] # This will return the 0th row
['username', 'name', 'password']
>>> matrix[0][1] # This will return the element from row 0, col 1
'name'
```